# How to call these interface methods?

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, interface, c#-3.0

Just wondering how to call this for my learning purpose. I know to call it via object creation when I do not use IIm or IIn.Display (i.e just by using public void Display();) However, I do not know how to call this.

```
public interface IIn
{
    void Display();
}
public interface IIM : IIn
{
    void Display();
}
public class temp : IIM
{
    void IIM.Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Displaying 1");
    }

     void IIn.Display()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Displaying 2 ");
     }

    static void Main()
    {
        temp t = new temp();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Is this a C# version specific question? If not, `c#` tag will be enough.

Comment: That code won't compile (you need a `new` keyword when declaring the IIM interface's Display() method, since it is hiding the one introduced by `IIn`)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Do you want to provide a code which shows that it won't compile?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: It does compile, as I am already learning myself, I asked this question because what if an interviewer asks me this question. I am saying to interviewers that I am very good or confident in OOP.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say "won't compile [without warnings]. Mea culpa!

Comment: @MatthewWatson: lol :P

Comment: @Deevinee Well, I have "warnings as errors" enabled, so it really *doesn't* compile for me. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Oh thank you, it is indeed a new learning for me as to set warnings as error, however, do not know how to do it, I will google out. Thank you very much again. Sorry, I am always smiling type, so never meant anything offensive. I am learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given

```
var t = new temp();
```

You only have to cast `t` to one of the interfaces... copying it in a variable of the interface type is enough:

```
IIM t1 = t;
IIn t2 = t;
t1.Display(); // Displaying 1
t2.Display(); // Displaying 2
```

or passing it as a parameter to a method:

```
static void MyShow(IIM t1, IIn t2)
{
    t1.Display(); // Displaying 1
    t2.Display(); // Displaying 2
}

MyShow(t, t);
```

or you can directly cast it and use the method:

```
((IIM)t).Display(); // Displaying 1
((IIn)t).Display(); // Displaying 2
```

note that if you had a third method in your class

```
public void Display()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Displaying 3 ");
}
```

this would call it

```
t.Display(); // Displaying 3
```

Comment: Thank you fantastic. Especially, I liked your 3rd approach, which I was looking for. Also, the class method explanation.